# Connecting two working computer hard drives via cable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have two computers, a desktop and a laptop. At the time that I purchased my laptop, my desktop was running linux and I had no desire to switch it to windows however I still wanted to play some games so I got a laptop capable of doing what I need to do on windows.  At this point I have gotten a copy of windows through my college and now want to use my desktop more again (considering how much I spent on it).

Problem is, all of my files are on my laptop but I like them being there so I can play games/work on projects when I'm not in my apartment.  What would be optimal is if I could run an Ethernet cable between the two computers and have them recognize each other as an external hard drive.  I googled a lot but it all came up connecting an external hard drive to two computers.  I'm open to using whatever cables I need, it doesn't necessarily have to be Ethernet, I'm also open to other suggestions if there is a different way I can accomplish the same task.  I'm trying to avoid network things because I'm on a public network and am not allowed to use a router (switch is OK though).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, I figured I'd ask before I go off and try to botch something together.  Also, another point might be that I have two hard drives in both computers (an SSD and HDD) I would prefer access to both but I can deal with access to just the HDD's which do not have any operating system bits on them.

Comment: So you want two copies of your data files to be on two different computers? What happens if you update one file on both computers, separately? Using some online shared files may be a more conflict-free permanent answer (if security isn't a big concern, or use encryption). If you just want to copy all the data from one drive to another, plug both drives into the desktop (SATA cables probably) boot and copy, then return the drives

Comment: Not necessarily two copies, just a way to plug in my laptop and have it seen as an external hard drive almost, or any way to access its file system really.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by making a small static network between the computers. This may or may not work between the computers directly, so you may want to try it with a switch between and without. Connect the two computers together with an Ethernet cable (possibly two with a switch in between) and then assign a static IP address to each machine (for example 137.22.47.1 on the first machine and 137.22.47.2 on the second) then make a Samba share on each machine, then use your file explorer to mount the network location at the assigned IP address on each machine.

Comment: I could just put the general internet through the switch as well correct? I'm not as good at networking as I should be.  From my limited knowledge, you connect the wall (router / modem / whatever) to the switch, and then the switch to both computers.  Then as you said, set up a static IP and do the rest.

Comment: @ozay34 No, you could not do this as you would need an IP either dynamically assigned by your local network, or in the case of a direct outside connection you'd need a dynamically assigned IP from your ISP. You said you cannot use routers? Why is this? If you can get a cheap WAN router and connect your internet to the WAN or Internet port (whatever it is labelled) and then connect the two computers to LAN ports, then you'd get internet, a private network on which your shares are invisible outside on the WAN port and the router will do the IP assigning for you automatically.

Comment: @ozay34 In the case of WiFi being the reason you aren't allowed a router, you can almost certainly turn WiFi off on all routers so they act as wired-only routers.

Comment: At that point whats the difference between that and a switch? as I said, I'm not as in the know how with networking as I should be.  I'm on a college network and cannot have a static IP assigned to my computer however I am given a host name that resolves to my dynamic IP.  I would assume a router messes around with the network in ways they don't want at college so they are not allowed.

Comment: Switches just act as a hub for data to be shared and routers specifically redirect packets and provide services such as dynamic IP transmitting and receive

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution to your problem would be using Network File and Printer Sharing service. You just [share a folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx), select accounts that have an access, and that's it. Be careful though because Windows by default allows to use obsolete network protocols that aren't secure, and disabling them requires very solid knowledge.

US-CERT recommends that users and administrators consider:

- [disabling SMBv1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows) and
- blocking all versions of SMB (you could achieve that with Windows Firewall) at the network boundary by blocking TCP port 445 with related protocols on UDP ports 137-138 and TCP port 139 (in your case that rule could be modified to "for non-local connections", and "non-local" means you should specify all addresses that not belong to your network). Please don't change your network profile to "Private", better add the access rule to "Public" one that prohibits any SMB by default.

These two actions are the very basic set of actions that you have to implement always, not only when you want to use file sharing service. Of course, there are lots of other things that you have to know to properly secure your network, and that cannot be explained with just a single answer.

Comment: "*by default allows to use obsolete network protocols that aren't secure, and disabling them requires very solid knowledge*" that knowledge would be excellent in your answer